# Android app tutorial (text disappearing on back command)

Tags: android

I am following the tutorial here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

When I enter some text into the field and press Send, it goes to the second screen with the larger text, so that part works.

When I click the "back" button on my phone, the text I inputted is still in the text field. But if I press the back button on the screen near the top of the program, the text I inputted is gone.

Why is this and how can I control / change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason for your issue** - Your app creates a new instance of activity when you click the back button in your app.

**To fix this**

In the back button where you call your first activity, add this line of code

```
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

**What happens with this flag ?**

When you use this flag, Android looks for an instance of the desired activity in your activity stack, starting from the front of the stack and scanning until it gets to the root/back of the stack. As soon as it finds an instance of the specified activity, it brings that one to the front (ie: if there are multiple instances of the specified activity it will bring to the front the most recent instance).

Comment: So without this flag, it just removes / re-creates the instance instead?

Comment: @JohnSmith, it will not remove from back stack. Instead, another instance of the same activity will be created and added to the backstack (in addition to the already available activity)

Comment: So if I were to keep going back and re-entering text, pressing send, going back, repeat, I would be creating a bunch of instances until memory runs out or something?

Comment: Why does this tutorial structure it that way? I guess using that flag is a must-have for devs who don't want their programs to hog up resources on repetition?

Comment: I suppose that's one of the differences between "Up" and "Back" functionality. @Prem So, do I have to create the intent and start the parent activity manually if I want to avoid the memory leak? Or can I somehow set the flag while still keeping the rest of the default "Up" implementation (enabled by declaring the parent activities in the manifest file and calling `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in activities' `onCreate()`s? As in that case I do not explicitly deal with the intents (to be able to set a flag).

Comment: @Janis, I am not able to understand clearly what you are trying to implement via option 2. But as far as your 1st question is concerned, YES it is always good to re-use the activity instances without creating new ones everytime. This can be done via Intent flags or by setting the flags in activity declaration in manifest xml file.

Comment: @JohnSmith, Yes Flags are important if you want to create an app with memory efficiency and user experience. No User will be happy if the data entered is lost everytime he traverses back to the old screen. right :)

Comment: @Prem Thank you, setting `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest file seems to do the trick! By the default "Up" implementation I meant what is described in http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#UpNav - you don't have to add code in "onOptionsItemSelected" for handling the event of "Up" button, as long as the parent activity is defined and "setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled" is called in "onCreate".